# Qt/QML: Save and abort settings

Tags: save, qml, settings

I am designing a GUI for my 3D printer. At the home screen you can chose between starting a new print or changing the settings (feedrates, acceleration etc.). Fot the settings I was following [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html) example. But unlinke as in the example, my settings are not properties of the GUI (like x postion, width etc.) but raw data that is entered through text fields and is insignificant to the GUI. The settings are saved at the end of the GUI in a .txt file which is later translated into a code for the printer.

My first question is, how do i design a save- and abort-button? The user should be able to change the text fields but the changes should only be terminal when the save button is pressed.

My second question is, should i ALWAYS read out the text fields? The settings usually shouldnt be changed, so is there a more efficient way? (read the text fields only when the save button was clicked, otherwise adopt the previous values?

For the save Button I was trying something like this, but i doesnt work:

```
Item {
     TextField {id: testField}
     Button {id: testButton; text: "Accept"; onClicked: settings.state = "inactive"}
     Settings {id:settings; property string state: "active"}
     state: settings.state
     states: [
          State {name: "active"}
          State {name:"inactive"; property alias test: testField.text}
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File operations must be done on C++ level. Following code will be a good example of showing open, save and edit operation in `Qt`.
It uses widget so add the following in `.pro` file.

```
QT += widgets
```

**qmlfile.h**

```
//qmlfile.h
#ifndef QMLFILE_H
#define QMLFILE_H

#include <QObject>

class QMLFile : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QMLFile(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE QString getFileContents() const;

    Q_INVOKABLE void saveFileContents(QString fileContents) const;
};

#endif
```

**qmlfile.cpp**

```
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>
#include "qmlfile.h"

QMLFile::QMLFile(QObject *parent): QObject(parent)
{

}

QString QMLFile::getFileContents() const
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(NULL, tr("Open File"), "/home", tr("Text Files (*.txt)"));
    qDebug() << "fileName:" << fileName;
    QFile file(fileName);
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return "";

    QString content = file.readAll();
    file.close();
    return content;
}

void QMLFile::saveFileContents(QString fileContents) const
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(NULL, tr("Save File"), "/home/ansh/data.txt", tr("Text Files (*.txt)"));

    QFile file(fileName);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "created file:" << fileName;
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << fileContents << endl;
        file.close();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "could not create file:" << fileName;
        return;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QApplication>
#include "qmlfile.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    QMLFile qmlFile;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("QMLFile", &qmlFile);
    QObject::connect((QObject*)view.engine(), SIGNAL(quit()), QApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));
    view.setSource(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360; height: 360

    Rectangle{
        id:buttons
        height: 50; width: parent.width; anchors.top: parent.top

        Row {
            Button {
                text: "open"
                onClicked: txt.text = QMLFile.getFileContents();
            }

            Button {
                text: "save"
                onClicked: QMLFile.saveFileContents(txt.text);
            }
            Button {
                text: "Abort"
                onClicked: Qt.quit()
            }
            spacing: 5
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id:textHandle
        width: parent.width; height: parent.height - buttons.height; anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        TextEdit{
            id: txt; anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

For the second question, since the settings are dynamic in nature it has to be read every time.